# How to receive notifications from Paypal

Tags: paypal

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction as I have next to no experience of integrating with PayPal.

I am wanting to set up a subscription service on a website I am working on. Initially I though I'd use the basic buttons Paypal provides and include some type of token in the return URL. I could then use the token to update my back-end systems that the user in question had paid.

I realised that I wouldn't receive notifications from Paypal if a user unsubscribes through the paypal website.

Is IPN the solution best suited for subscriptions.

Thanks, David

Comment: Yes, IPN is best suited for receiving notifcations and updating the backend

Comment: Thanks Vimal, there seems to be multiple ways paypal offer to do things and I just wanted to make sure I was on the right path.

Comment: Why do you think you won't received unsubribe notifications? I do.

Comment: Hi ejp. What I meant was that without using IPN I wouldn't receive notification if a user just logged onto the paypal website and unsubscribed.

Comment: You will receive the IPN even if they cancel profile from their account . Something like this :http://screencloud.net/v/v1sV

Comment: So why not use IPN then?

Comment: That's what my question was, 'Is IPN the solution best suited for subscriptions.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **IPN** is best suited for receiving notifcations and updating the backend.
There is a similar feature called "Payment Data Transfer" (PDT)
But, PDT applies for only Website payment Standard and it has few limitations.

I would recommend using IPN, as its a generic feature for all the paypal products available and 
its more secure and reliable than PDT.[Advantages](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/)